# Collecting data from 3G modem

Tags: java, modem, 3g, imei

How can I extract data from 3G modem in JAVA using eclipse Luna?

The data I want to extract is:
The SIM card information
- IMSI

The information in the data key

- IMEI
- Manufacturer

Network information:

- Minimal Signal Level, average and Maximum.
- Bandwidth of the radio link band (Max Flow in downlink and amount).

KPIs below will be considered :

· Maximum and minimum flow rate in downlink

· Average flow in downlink

· Maximum and minimum flow rate in uplink

· Average flow related amount

· Average level of the received signal

· Average Time Connection

Please help me i am so desperate.

Comment: Could you also show the community some code? Would be great to atleast show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know the make and model of the modem.  Then do a google search for the AT commands or the CNS protocol of it.  You can find this information for the Sierra Wireless cards and connect to them over a COM port.  You can find more information on this on their developer forum.